# C#: Two different classes from two different XSDs

Tags: c#, class, xsd

I am struggling on how to setup a function that returns a class. The caveat being that the XSD used to create the response classes differs between the Test and Stage environments. The class I deserialize from XML depends on the environment I am hitting. What is the right thing to do here so I can support both environments (which will grow to three in the future)?

```
public async Task<*thingie*> ReadDataAsync(List of serial numbers, env)
{
  if(env == Test)
  {
    url = https://test.mycompany.com/db/getData
    xml = <response>
    var respA = xml.DeserializeXml<Xsd125.dataResponse>(); //XSD v1.25
  }
  elseif(env == Prod)
  {
    url = https://prod.mycompany.com/db/getData
    xml = <response>
    var respB = xml.DeserializeXml<Xsd129.dataResponse>(); //XSD v1.29
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add more clarifications on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you saying that in different environments, the class you deserialize into will be different? If so, you're going to need to find a common Interface or base class (perhaps abstract) if you want to do what you show; you need to replace `*thingie*` with something

Comment: Yes depending on the environment, the definition in the XSD is different. Sometimes the differences are small, sometimes quite huge. So yeah I am looking what to do with *thingie*. I'm just lost as to what my next step should be.

Comment: Btw, I have already converted the XSDs from the third-party into classes. Each version has its own namespace. Thus the Xsd125.dataResponse and Xsd129.dataResponse.

Comment: The contract in the server is wrong. I had this scenario from a third party and I couldn't do anything. Bad programmers are everywhere. In this scenario I used differents classes and repeat the code. With an enum I can choose. In my case I couldn't hereby any interface. For sure is a bad idea make 2 DLLs and change it if the environment changes, don't do it. Use the same code, just repeat inside. BUT take note if you have to change something, or if sandbox doesn't work like prod, the code may be different.

Comment: Nothing I can do with how the third party provides the response. But I'm not sure how to structure this or how to create a base class or interface to support both response types. I have read some tutorials on interfaces but am completely lost.